# Actual data of single photon double slit experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, double-slit-experiment

I am interested in mapping the actual location of single photon impacts in a double slit experiment as a time series. In other words, I would like three data points for each photon measurement - the time, the x location on the screen, and the y location on the screen. I dont know if this has actually been done. Probably it is too boring and most people would expect a random distribution. But one never knows - A photon appearing on the right half of the screen might be followed more often by a photon on the left half, etc. Since I do not have the experimental equipment to do this ( a single photon source is needed and this is not easy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source), I wonder if the data has ever been recorded that I could just analyze? Since the double slit experiment has also been verified with electrons, atoms and even molecules, I suppose a simple electron gun that shoots single electrons at a double slit to a phosphor screen could be used. But I dont have this either (threw away my old CRTs) and even if I did, I wouldn't know how to get accurately timed single electrons out of it. And then I would have to know the quantum spin as well to control for that variable. But perhaps such data is available though I dont know how to find it. Accurately timing impacts was never actually recorded to my knowledge.

Comment: https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/single-photon-interference

Comment: thank you mmesser314. I emailed Wolfgang and he was kind enough to reply.  Unfortunately he did not collect that data for the paper you referenced.